# Why does a junction created in Powershell have \??\ in it?

Tags: windows, powershell

When I create a junction in Windows 10 Enterprise 1809 using `mklink /J c:\foo c:\bar` I can see the new junction using `dir` as `<JUNCTION>     foo [c:\bar]`

When I create the junction using Powershell 17763 using `New-Item -ItemType Junction -Path c:\foo -Target c:\bar` I see the new junction using `dir` as `<JUNCTION>     foo [\??\c:\bar]`

Why is there a discrepancy and what does the `\??\` mean?

I haven't found any impact on functionality as of yet, but have not done exhaustive testing (nor do I really have the time to do exhaustive testing)

Comment: *\??\c:\bar* is real, nt path of bar. it always have \??\ (or \GLOBAL??\ ) prefix

Comment: Thanks, RbMm - In that case my question would be: Why does the `mklink` version of the junction not have `\??\\` in it?

Comment: all version and always have \??\ prefix. simply some version **not show** it. different only in way how it displayed

Comment: [reparse point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_reparse_data_buffer) have 2 names - *SubstituteName* and *PrintName*. *SubstituteName* - this is *NT* format path to target. it usually start with \??\ or \GLOBAL??\ prefix. *PrintName* can be any. it not interpreted by system. may be different utilities set different *PrintName* (this not affect any) and of course question - you view *PrintName* or real target  *SubstituteName*

Comment: "\\?\" and "\\.\" are both shorthand prefixes that map to the local device-link object directory of the current user. (Note that an object directory is not a filesystem directory.) The Windows API translates them both to the native NT prefix "\??\". A user's local device-link object directory is really "\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<logon session ID>", which typically contains per-user mapped and subst drives. This object directory implicitly shadows "\GLOBAL??", the global device-link object directory, which has system device links such as "C:" -> "\Device\HarddiskVolume2".

Comment: Back to PowerShell, that it uses "\??\" in the DOS print name is conceptually wrong. It *happens* that recent versions of Windows are so used to hardly anyone really understanding this (not because it's complicated, but because it's poorly documented and because people are lazy), that they've decided to handle "\??\" as if it's "\\?\" when opening a path. Just because they allow it doesn't mean it's not nonsense. The Windows API does not specify "\??\" as a reserved prefix. It's an NT path, and if you pass it to `GetFullPathNameW`, the result is mangled.